# Derivation practice problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to solve the following problem.

> Find the derivative of $x^{10}(x^2+1)^{10}$.

First I used the product rule, then the chain rule, yielding $$10x^9(x^2+1)^{10} + 20x^{11}(x^2 + 1)^9.$$

My problem is that the result in the solution manual is different, namely
$$10(3x^2 + 1)x^9(x^2+1)^9.$$

Did I miss something here? What's wrong with my version?

Comment: They factored out the common factor. They expected full simplification (which is standard practice).

Comment: Fortunately, this question was easy. But for future questions, it will help if you learn how to show the equations in the question text instead of in a linked picture. This also helps people who are trying to write answers. You can start learning here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two solutions are the same.
Starting from your solution :
$$10x^9(x^2+1)^{10}+20x^{11}(x^2+1)^9=(x^2+1)^9(10x^9(x^2+1)+20x^{11})\\=(x^2+1)^910x^9(x^2+1+2x^2)=10(3x^2+1)x^9(x^2+1)^9$$

So your solution is the same as the MIT one.